# how to create a new column by subtraction of different cells followed by a specific string for each row

Tags: r

So I have a data structure that looks like this

```
       V4  V5     V6     V7  V8    V9    V10 V11   V12  id            date  start yellow
3   10552 180 yellow     NA  NA           NA  NA       101 20130826T155649      3  10552
4   19502 150 yellow     NA  NA           NA  NA       101 20130826T155649  12002  19502
5   28957 130 yellow  30457 160 brake  31457 170   red 101 20130826T155649  22452  28957
6   46662 160 yellow  47912 185   red     NA  NA       101 20130826T155649  38657  46662
7   55612 130 yellow  58362 185   red     NA  NA       101 20130826T155649  49112  55612
8   66567 140 yellow  69167 192   red  69267 194 crash 101 20130826T155649  59562  66567
9   86532 130 yellow  88182 163 brake  89532 173   red 101 20130826T155649  80027  86532
10 101337 130 yellow 103087 165   red 103187 167 brake 101 20130826T155649  93282 101337
```

So what happened is I have a really messy table. So you can see, the first column represents the time for the third column, yellow, and the forth column represents the time for the 6th column. What I'm trying to do is that I'm trying to do the time difference between brake and yellow, and then create a new column. And as you can see some rows have no brake. I'm just wondering how to create a new column from this.

the second question is I'm trying to create two new column for crash and no brake, meaning if the row has "crash" or does not have "brake", it would be 1, so I'm guessing I want want to do a True false thing and represent it with 1 and 0 so I can add them up and count. I was thinking doing a for loop but I'm kinda stuck. I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: Could you try to use `dput(...)` on your data and copy-paste what you get into your question? That would make it easier for people to help you. Also try to format the data properly as code.

Answer (score 0):

Because your data frame has "brake" and "crash" in either V9 or V12, the first thing I would do would be to create a column containing the time of these events if they happened, and otherwise `NA`:

```
dat$brake <- ifelse(dat$V9 == "brake", dat$V7, ifelse(dat$V12 == "brake", dat$V10, NA))
dat$crash <- ifelse(dat$V9 == "crash", dat$V7, ifelse(dat$V12 == "crash", dat$V10, NA))
```

Now you can pretty easily add the columns you want ("difference between brake and yellow time" or "crash and no brake"):

```
dat$yb <- dat$brake - dat$yellow
dat$cnb <- as.numeric(!is.na(dat$crash) & is.na(dat$brake))
#       V4  V5     V6     V7  V8    V9    V10 V11   V12  id            date start yellow  brake crash   yb cnb
# 1  10552 180 yellow     NA  NA  <NA>     NA  NA  <NA> 101 20130826T155649     3  10552     NA    NA   NA   0
# 2  19502 150 yellow     NA  NA  <NA>     NA  NA  <NA> 101 20130826T155649 12002  19502     NA    NA   NA   0
# 3  28957 130 yellow  30457 160 brake  31457 170   red 101 20130826T155649 22452  28957  30457    NA 1500   0
# 4  46662 160 yellow  47912 185   red     NA  NA  <NA> 101 20130826T155649 38657  46662     NA    NA   NA   0
# 5  55612 130 yellow  58362 185   red     NA  NA  <NA> 101 20130826T155649 49112  55612     NA    NA   NA   0
# 6  66567 140 yellow  69167 192   red  69267 194 crash 101 20130826T155649 59562  66567     NA 69267   NA   1
# 7  86532 130 yellow  88182 163 brake  89532 173   red 101 20130826T155649 80027  86532  88182    NA 1650   0
# 8 101337 130 yellow 103087 165   red 103187 167 brake 101 20130826T155649 93282 101337 103187    NA 1850   0
```

Comment: awesome. so my data is more broken than I thought. so files it has 15 or even 18 columns.  so do I just write this code:
dat$brake <- ifelse(dat$V9 == "brake", dat$V7, ifelse(dat$V12 == "brake", dat$V10, ifelse(dat$V15 == "brake", b$V13, NA))